# Desativar teclado virtual Coletor CipherLab 9700 via PHP

Tags: javascript, html, teclado

Criei 2 paginas em `PHP`, para executar no coletor:

[CipherLab 9700](http://www.cipherlab.com/catalog.asp?CatID=7&SubcatID=230)

Ele está executando normalmente e fazendo o que quero, a única coisa que não estou gostando é que ele fica abrindo o teclado digital e com isso sobrepondo o meu `form`.

Eu não posso desativar diretamente o teclado no aparelho pois existem outras aplicações que utilizam ele.

Eu conseguiria bloquear o teclado virtual via `PHP`?

Segue o campo do meu `form`, caso seja necessário:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="temp.php" method="post" name="frmControl">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tag" class="col-lg-2 control-label">TAG</label>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tag" name="tag">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Qual sistema operacional esse aparelho utiliza?

Comment: Microsoft Windows CE Version: 6.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembro que quando tava na faculdade tive que desenvolver um script pra celular. Na epoca quase todos tinham teclados físicos, e o script tinha que fazer mais ou menos a mesma coisa.

```
$('#no_keyboard input').focus(function(){
    $('.focused').removeClass("focused");
    $(this).blur().addClass('focused');
    text = $('.focused').val();
});

$(window).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which != 8){
        text = text+String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    }
    else{
       e.preventDefault();
       text = text.substring(0,text.length-1);
    }
    $('.focused').val(text);
});
```

O código acima tira o foco do input, depois pega tudo que for digitado e coloca no ultimo campo focado.

Na prática ele até funciona, mas precisa ser melhorado para ser utilizado em projetos. https://jsfiddle.net/s2ev69jz/9/